# Reverse proxy with httputil and gorilla/mux

Tags: http, go, reverse-proxy, gorilla, mux

I've been trying to reverse proxy some of my requests internally with `httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(*Url)`
I noticed that gorilla mux is not happy with this so I found a fix online that solved the issue for `GET` requests.
However, it seems like like `GET` is the only request that will be reverse proxied correctly.

`u = generated URL with url.Parse`

```
api.Path("/feature").Methods("POST").HandlerFunc(handler(httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(u)))

func handler(p *httputil.ReverseProxy) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.URL.Path = mux.Vars(r)["path"]
        p.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

This works fine for `GET` requests, but when sending a `POST` or `PATCH` the receiving http method is set as `GET`. I have confirmed that the proxy's `r.Method` is `POST` on one end and `GET` on the other.
Has anyone encountered this issue before, or know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

This error was caused by the route returning a 301 still unclear why. ReverseProxy's fallback behavior on 301, 302, 303 is to support RFC 2616

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18570
This rewrites the Method to `GET`